# Spark DF: Schema for type Unit is not supported

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, dataframe

I am new to Scala and Spark and trying to build on some samples I found. Essentially I am trying to call a function from within a data frame to get State from zip code using Google API..
I have the code working separately but not together ;(
Here is the piece of code not working...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Unit is not supported
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:716)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:2837)
    at MovieRatings$.getstate(MovieRatings.scala:51)
    at MovieRatings$$anonfun$4.apply(MovieRatings.scala:48)
    at MovieRatings$$anonfun$4.apply(MovieRatings.scala:47)...
Line 51 starts with def getstate = udf {(zipcode:String)...
...
```

**code:**

```
 userDF.createOrReplaceTempView("Users")
    // SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by Spark
   val zipcodesDF = spark.sql("SELECT distinct zipcode, zipcode as state FROM Users")
 //  zipcodesDF.map(zipcodes => "zipcode: " + zipcodes.getAs[String]("zipcode") + getstate(zipcodes.getAs[String]("zipcode"))).show()
  val colNames = zipcodesDF.columns
val cols = colNames.map(cName => zipcodesDF.col(cName))
val theColumn = zipcodesDF("state")
val mappedCols = cols.map(c => 
  if (c.toString() == theColumn.toString()) getstate(c).as("transformed") else c)
  val newDF = zipcodesDF.select(mappedCols:_*).show()
  }
 def getstate = udf {(zipcode:String) => {
val url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+zipcode
val result = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString
val address = parse(result) 
val shortnames = for {
         JObject(address_components) <- address
         JField("short_name", short_name)  <- address_components
          } yield short_name
val state = shortnames(3)
//return state.toString()
val stater = state.toString()

}
  }
```

Comment: your `UDF` doesn't return anything because you commented out the `return state.toString()` part.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.. I think I figured it out. Here is the code that works. One thing to note is Google API has restriction so some valid zip codes don't have state info.. not an issue for me though.

```
            private def loaduserdata(spark: SparkSession): Unit = {
          import spark.implicits._
           // Create an RDD of User objects from a text file, convert it to a Dataframe
          val userDF = spark.sparkContext
            .textFile("examples/src/main/resources/users.csv")
            .map(_.split("::"))
            .map(attributes => users(attributes(0).trim.toInt,  attributes(1), attributes(2).trim.toInt, attributes(3), attributes(4)))
            .toDF()
          // Register the DataFrame as a temporary view
          userDF.createOrReplaceTempView("Users")
          // SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by Spark
         val zipcodesDF = spark.sql("SELECT distinct zipcode, substr(zipcode,1,5) as state FROM Users ORDER BY zipcode desc") //  zipcodesDF.map(zipcodes => "zipcode: " + zipcodes.getAs[String]("zipcode") + getstate(zipcodes.getAs[String]("zipcode"))).show()
        val colNames = zipcodesDF.columns
      val cols = colNames.map(cName => zipcodesDF.col(cName))
      val theColumn = zipcodesDF("state")
      val mappedCols = cols.map(c => 
        if (c.toString() == theColumn.toString()) getstate(c).as("state") else c)
        val geoDF = zipcodesDF.select(mappedCols:_*)//.show()
      geoDF.createOrReplaceTempView("Geo")
        }
       val getstate = udf {(zipcode: String) => 
           val url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+zipcode
           val result = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString
           val address = parse(result) 
          val statenm = for {
                      JObject(statename) <- address
                      JField("types", JArray(types)) <- statename
                      JField("short_name", JString(short_name)) <- statename
                     if types.toString().equals("List(JString(administrative_area_level_1), JString(political))")
                     //  if types.head.equals("JString(administrative_area_level_1)")
                    } yield short_name
           val str = if (statenm.isEmpty.toString().equals("true")) "N/A" else statenm.head        
           }
```

Comment: If you are interested, please see this data on Tableau Public: https://public.tableau.com/views/MovieRatings_7/Geo?:embed=y&:display_count=yes